# How to display the number of articles published per user

Tags: wp-query

How to display the number of articles published per user excluding users who do not publish articles. My message type is recipe. I would like to receive a code to get there in wp-query
thank you very much for your help

I give you a piece of code.
Thanks to this code I am able to display the total number of recipes, but I would have liked to have this:
User A posted 14 cooking recipes, User B posted 2 cooking recipes
ect..
user member1 should have 2 recipes

```
<?php
// 1. We define the arguments to define what we want to recover 
$args = array ( 'post_type' => 'recipe', 'posts_per_page' => '16', );

// 2. We run the WP Query 
// The Query 
$the_query = new WP_Query ($args);

// 3. we display the number of messages and the authors!
 // The Loop 
if ($the_query-> have_posts ()) {
 echo count_user_posts (2, $args); 
echo 'recipes for'; 
echo get_the_author (2, $args); 
echo '<br>'; 
echo count_user_posts (1, $args); 
echo 'recipes for';
 echo get_the_author (1, $args);

// 3. We launch the loop to display the articles and the authors! 
// The Loop 
echo '<ul>'; 
while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) ​{ 
$the_query-> the_post (); 
echo '<li>'. get_the_title (). '<li>'; 
echo '<li>'. get_the_author (). '<li>';
​}
​echo '<ul>';
​}
​else { 
// no posts found }
/ * Restore original Post Data * / 
wp_reset_postdata ();
​?>
```

[image]

Comment: Display the number where?

Comment: thank you for the answer. on a simple php page for the moment I manage to display all the articles of all the users with this code      `<?php  
$args = array(     'post_type' => 'recette' );
 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
echo $my_query->found_posts . " articles trouvés";  
?>`

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/396171/edit) if you want to provide updates, code snippets, etc.

Comment: Here I have modified
I'm looking for a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to user IDs, you can use the [count_user_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/) function.

You would get the number of posts by a user like this:

```
//Assume the variable $thisUser is equal to a valid user ID
$ThisUserCount = count_user_posts($thisUser, 'recipe');
```

EDIT:
Where you're calling the count_user_posts() function, you're passing it the array $args instead of the post type, 'recipe'.

```
<?php
// 1. We define the arguments to define what we want to recover
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'recipe',
    'posts_per_page' => '16',
);

// 2. We run the WP Query
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query ($args);

// 3. we display the number of messages and the authors!
// The Loop
if ($the_query-> have_posts()) {
    //Set arguments to grab all authors with published recipes, and order them by user ID
    $authorArgs = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'has_published_posts' => array('recipe'),
    );

    //Create an array of all authors with recipes published
    $recipeAuthors = get_users($authorArgs);

    //Loop through each recipe author
    foreach($recipeAuthors as $user){
        //Output user post count for recipes
        echo count_user_posts($user->ID, 'recipe');
        echo ' recipes for ';

        //Output user's display name
        echo $user->display_name;
        echo '<br />';
    }

    // 3. We launch the loop to display the articles and the authors!
    // The Loop
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($the_query-> have_posts()) {
        $the_query-> the_post();
        echo '<li>'. get_the_title(). '</li>';
        echo '<li>'. get_the_author(). '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata ();​?>
```

Also, your get_the_author(2,$args) function calls are not correct. get_the_author() does not accept any parameters anymore, and it only returns the Display Name of the author of the current post in the Loop.

Comment: Good evening
Thank you for the answer and the code but it does not work ... nothing is returned, I modified my request message it will be clearer

Comment: I edited my answer. you didn't implement the count_user_posts() correctly. The second parameter isn't looking for an array like $args, it wants either a string equal to the name of a single post type, or an array of strings for different post types you're trying to count.

Comment: user member1 should have 2 recipes .

Comment: Take a look at the changes i just made after the 2 lines that say echo 'recipes for';. I replaced your get_the_author() calls with the correct way to call an author's name when trying to pass the user ID.

Comment: a very big thank you for the code but I have an error:
A critical error has occurred on this site. Please check your site administration email inbox for more information.

Comment: Try commenting out all of the code posted in this question/answer, and just put the count_user_posts(2,'recipe') in, and see if it returns how many posts user id #2 should have? if that's correct, then uncomment out the next 3 lines to see if it will return 'recipes for' and the display name for user #2.

Comment: thank you very much for the help i tried to document part 1 of the id
I still have the error. then I have documented part 2 and still the error. and finally I have documented part 3 and I still have the error

Comment: so if you document/comment parts 1 2 and 3, does it still return an error, because if so, the error is from something else outside of the code you posted. If all 3 sections documented out, and no errors, keep it all documented, and add the following before section 1 and see if it errors:
echo count_user_posts(2, 'recipe');

Comment: this time no error with everything to comment except the echo I just received. Thank you very much for your patience

Comment: here is the line that was problematic
wp_reset_postdata ();
a very big thank you for this help
 everything works fine. then I ask an additional question

Comment: Hello a big thank you for your code this is really great with regard to the first code. for each new user who publishes a recipe, I should add code to the existing code to add this part of code // THIS LINE WILL ECHO HOW MANY 'recette' POSTS USER ID #3 HAS echo count_user_posts(3, 'recette'); echo 'recettes for'; $user = get_user_by( 'ID', 3 ); echo $user->display_name; echo '<br>'; // THIS LINE WILL ECHO HOW MANY 'recette' POSTS USER ID #4 HAS ect...is there a way for this to automatically face with a loop and once again a big thank you

Comment: Take a look at the updated code. I replaced the hard-coded id numbers for #1 and #2 with a looping function that grabs all users with published recipes, then loops through each one and outputs their recipe count and display name.

Comment: Good evening
a big thank you for the code it's really very kind of you. everything works wonderfully

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to display authors who have posted at least one article in your custom post type you can ignore the above code and just do this:

```
// Array of WP_User objects.
$authors = get_users();

// Loop thru the array and get the post count for each user
foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
    $posts = count_user_posts($author->ID, 'movies');

    // Only return users who have at least one post 
    if ($posts > 0):
        echo '<p><span>' . esc_html( $author->display_name ) . ': ' . $posts . '</span>';
    endif; 
}

// Only Necessary if you're running another loop or query on the page
wp_reset_postdata ();​
```

Good luck!

Comment: hello, many thanks for the code, that's really nice, have a nice day